# How to move top 100Million records (or) 1GB file from .txt file to new file in unix

Tags: file, unix, sed, split

I am trying to

Input file : input.txt
No of line in file: 21194896560
File size ~ 230GB
system free space is 30GB.

I am trying to

1. move top 1GB file from input.txt file to first1gb.txt Once I proceed this file and want to extract 2nd file
2. move second 1GB file from input.txt file to second1gb.txt

I am trying this command

```
split -b 1g myfile segment
```

with this I am able to extract first 1GB file, but unable to remove 1gb data from input file and unable to get another 1 gb file..

Any help?

Comment: You mention the number of lines in the file which implies it is text, but you are cutting it on byte boundaries (e.g. 1GB) which could be in the middle of a line, so this seems unlikely. Is your file lines of text or binary data? Is it ok to cut the file in the middle of a line?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about what you want to achieve. Obviously there is not enough space to split the file into 230 chunks of 1GB each. Do you want to extract the first chunk of 1GB, process it, delete it, extract the second chunk of 1GB, process it, delete it etc until the end of the file? Please clarify this *in your question*. File names `first1gb.txt`, `second1gb.txt` etc. are difficult to create.

Answer (score 1):

Something along, untested:

Copy the first 1GB from the input.txt into first1gb.txt file:

```
dd if=input.txt of=first1gb.txt bs=1M count=1024
```

Move data from 2GB to end of file to the beginning of the file. Left shift the file 1GB. In C pseudocode `memmove(input.txt, input.txt+1GB, sizeof(input.txt)-1GB)`.

```
dd if=input.txt of=input.txt conv=notrunc bs=1M skip=1024
```

Remove last 1GB of the file:

```
truncate -s -1G input.txt
```

Then repeat for next 1GB.

To omit left shifting and simplify truncating, if you want to process the whole file, with some "maths" knowing the size of the file, you can start extracting the chunks from the end. This would greatly increase the execution time, as the left shifting of a big file is going to take forever. By starting from the end, you will only in total copy the files bytes once chunk after chunk.

> How to move top 100Million records

Similarly, extract the first 100milion lines.

```
head -n $((100*1000*1000*1000)) input.txt > first100m.txt
```

Left shift the file 100 milions lines.

```
dd if=input.txt of=input.txt bs=1M conv=notrunc iflag=skip_bytes skip=$(stat -c %s first100m.txt)
```

Truncate excess of bytes:

```
truncate -s -$(stat -c %s first100m.txt) input.txt
```

---

Example with a file with 10 lines extracting two lines at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
rm -f *.txt
seq 10 > input.txt
lines=2
for ((i = 0; 1; ++i)); do
        if [[ ! -s input.txt ]]; then
                break
        fi
        head -n "$lines" input.txt > "output_$i.txt"
        size=$(stat -c %s "output_$i.txt")
        dd of=input.txt if=input.txt bs=1M conv=notrunc iflag=skip_bytes skip="$skip"
        truncate -s -"$skip" input.txt
done
tail -n +1 *.txt
```

Script outputs:

```
==> input.txt <==

==> output_0.txt <==
1
2

==> output_1.txt <==
3
4

==> output_2.txt <==
5
6

==> output_3.txt <==
7
8

==> output_4.txt <==
9
10
```

Below is the code with the same result, but extracting from the file from the end. Missing the `dd` left shifting the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
rm -f *.txt
seq 10 > input.txt
lines=2
inputlines=$(wc -l < input.txt)
chunks=$(( inputlines / lines ))
for ((i = chunks - 1; i >= 0; --i)); do
        if [[ ! -s input.txt ]]; then
                break
        fi
        tail -n "$lines" input.txt > "output_$i.txt"
        size="$(stat -c %s "output_$i.txt")"
        truncate -s -"$size" input.txt
done
tail -n +1 *.txt
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this. Your second line implies it's ok to use the same file for input as for output with `dd`? And you grab 1GB of data from the start of the file but then truncate 1GB from the end? Surely you'd need to `dd` the **last GB** and then truncate?

Comment: `mplies it's ok to use the same file for input as for output with dd?` yes (?) `you grab 1GB of data from the start of the file` yes `the truncate 1GB from the end?` yes `need to dd the last GB and then truncate?` I do not understand, no, I left shift the file 1 GB and remove the right-most 1GB. I understood "move 1GB from input.txt" requested by OP, as copy 1GB from the file, and then remove that copied 1GB.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That was fun, I added examples and more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to chop input.txt into 1GB files and you want to avoid reading the file over and over, try:

```
parallel -k --dr -vv --block 1G --pipepart -a bigfile.txt copy {#}.txt trunc |
  tac |
  perl -pe '/0 0 (\d+)/; $size=$1; s/copy/cat >/; s/trunc/;truncate -s $size bigfile.txt/' > doit.sh
bash doit.sh
```

It (ab)uses GNU Parallel's block detection to determine where to chop the file. The block detection will use binary search to find the next \n and it thus pretty fast.

`tac` changes the order of the commands, so we work our way from the end to the start.

Finally we change GNU Parallel's "`cat` from byte a to byte b" to copy that into a file, and change `trunc` into `truncate -s $size`. We get the size from the block detection.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU Parallel):

```
cat bigFile | parallel -j 1 -pipe -n 1G 'cat >1GFile; processFile <1GFile' && rm 1GFile
```

Uses parallel sequentially splitting each process into 1G lines and then uses `processFile` to read those lines, finally once the `bigFile` has ended, clean up the `1GFile`.

N.B. Could be made faster if records are fixed length see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#pipe)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to process the file in chunks of 1 GB, then you can do this without temporary files:

```
myprocess() {
  # Do your processing here. Must read from stdin
  wc -l
}
export -f myprocess

parallel -j1 --pipepart -a bigfile.txt --block 1G myprocess
```

If you need the 1 GB to be in a file (and not just on standard input (stdin)) you can add `--cat`. It is slower because it will first generate the temporary file.

```
myprocess() {
  # Do your processing here. $1 is the temporary file
  wc -l "$1"
}
export -f myprocess

parallel -j1 --cat --pipepart -a bigfile.txt --block 1G myprocess {}
```

GNU Parallel will split at \n around 1GB. If you need exactly 1GB (and thus want to cut in the middle of a line), you can add `--recend ''`.